# Unknown Indentation Error in the following code

Tags: python, django, django-forms

this is the code:
3nd line is giving error.

```
class RawMassegeForm(forms.Form):
    subject = forms.CharField(widget= forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder':'Enter your Subject'}))
    name = forms.CharField(widget= forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder':'Enter your Name'}))
    email = forms.EmailField(widget= forms.EmailInput(attrs={'placeholder':'Enter your email'}))
    message = forms.TextField(widget= forms.Textarea(attrs={'placeholder':'Enter Your Message 
    here...'}))
```

Comment: I‘m sure the error message tells you exactly what is wrong. We cannot, since we cannot see the error message.

Comment: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

Comment: The code you posted is mixing tabs and spaces for indentation

Answer (score 0):

You can't just split lines like

```
    message = forms.TextField(widget= forms.Textarea(attrs={'placeholder':'Enter Your Message 
    here...'}))
```

Instead, e.g.

```
class RawMassegeForm(forms.Form):
    subject = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={"placeholder": "Enter your Subject"})
    )
    name = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={"placeholder": "Enter your Name"})
    )
    email = forms.EmailField(
        widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={"placeholder": "Enter your email"})
    )
    message = forms.TextField(
        widget=forms.Textarea(
            attrs={"placeholder": "Enter Your Message here..."}
        )
    )
```

is perfectly fine.

Comment: line that has name variable is giving error now